# SetOnClickListener in an IF statement not detecting clicks

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm creating an app that has a `toggle-button` in the `toolbar` that makes an `appbar` drop down.The problem is that I want the `appbar` to retract back up when I press anywhere on the screen, but it doesn't detect the clicks on the screen.

**Edit**
This is what the dropdown looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQvs0.gif
Right now I'm simply hiding and showing the bar instead of animating it for simplicity.

I've tried to set an `OnClickListener` to the underlying layout (the coordinatorlayout) when the `dropdown` is opened, but it's not detecting any clicks.

**Code**
I'm using XML tags to detect if the appbar is either closed or opened on the moment of the click, default in XML file is "off".

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        final View view = getView();

        final AppBarLayout yearBar = view.findViewById(R.id.yearbar);
        final CoordinatorLayout cLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.main_content);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.year_dropdown:
                if (yearBar.getTag().toString().trim().equals("on")) {
                    yearBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    yearBar.setTag("off");

                } else if (yearBar.getTag().toString().trim().equals("off")) {
                    yearBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    yearBar.setTag("on");

                    cLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            yearBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            yearBar.setTag("off");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Click detected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
                return true;

            case R.id.settings:
                // Open settings
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I think that the problem lies in the fact that I'm setting the OnClickListener in the else-if statement, but I've got no idea how else I could set the OnClickListener  to only be active when the dropdown has opened. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a `Boolean` variable to holds the state of dropDown. set onClick outside of the if statement and check state in it.
It's the simplest way but you can use selection state of your view as this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
         if(v.selected()){
             yearBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             yearBar.setTag("off");
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Click detected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else{
              //do somthing else
         }
         v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem right, but I know that its very bad practice to set button click on condition. So first you move this code in onCreate() without any condition:

```
cLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        yearBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        yearBar.setTag("off");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Click detected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

now if you want give condition you must call in onClick.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit using a tag, as already you can use the view visibility boolean instead.
Also no need to add the `onClickListener` inside the condition of the switch case of the menu item
you can put it normally in `onCreateView()` of the fragment

You can do something like below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    final AppBarLayout yearBar = view.findViewById(R.id.yearbar);
    CoordinatorLayout cLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.main_content);

    cLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (yearBar.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Click detected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                yearBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    View view = getView();
    AppBarLayout yearBar = view.findViewById(R.id.yearbar);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.year_dropdown:

            if (yearBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                yearBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (yearBar.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                yearBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return true;

        case R.id.settings:
            // Open settings
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```